# Got problems with Intero. (or Haskero)

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, intero

When I put on mouse on phrases, intero says `"Couldn't guess that module name. Does it exists"`. It whines on function name, module name, every word of string, and even space or tab character.

It does not cause fatal error or stop compiling, but it's irritating. How can I solve this?

I am using Stack, Haskero on VS Code. I also tried `stack ghci --with-ghc-intero`, but it doesn't work. How can I solve this?

Comment: When this happens, are you looking at a file that's part of a dependent library, or perhaps some unit tests? Does this also happen in the `Main` module?

Comment: @Mark seemann It was `Main.hs` file. Also happens in other files, even non-stack files.

Comment: Have you executed `stack build intero` before opening Visual Studio Code?

Comment: @MarkSeemann I have and I'm having a similar problem

Comment: I also have this problem.